# Start Java event on date/time based on database row

Tags: java, listener

I'm trying to make a Listener (or something like that?) that will start a specific event when a date field from a database row is the same as the current time. Of course I can trigger every second to check if the date/time is the same as the current, but I think that is quite expansive. There should be a better alternative..

What I trying to do is the following:
I have several (for example football) matches scheduled in my database. At the specific time when the match should start, I will start a event in my Java app. This could be 1 or more matches at that time.

Comment: Which database do you use?

Comment: ya which database are you using?

Comment: The database is not important. I should trigger a event in my Java application.

Answer (score 5):

I understand that you are trying to schedule execution of future events in java app not in database.

You should consider using [`ScheduledExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) method `schedule` to delay execution of task to specific point in time.

The only problem you have to solve is how you synchronize task in database with this in schedule.

EDIT:
If you keep map with taskID->ScheduledFuture object returned you can easily call cancel on the object to remove task. But you have to add some kind of last-modification column to detect new and updated tasks and query database to check if there are not any new tasks.

Comment: Yeah, I meant to start future events in java and not in the database. The ScheduledExecutorService is something promising. I will take a look at this tonight! So thanks for you help. I think the best way to synchronize this is to add all the database time/dates by starting the app. And when a event changes from date, also update the ScheduledExecutorService.